# Render additional info in cell when row is hovered in ag-grid

Tags: css, angular, performance, ag-grid, angular-directive

I am using angular (^8.2.14) and ag-grid-community (^20.1.0).

I try to achieve the following effect: when the user hovers a specific row, one column shows an additional button which may be clicked.

What does work?
The column with the wanted behaviour gets rendered by a custom cell renderer component which implements the [ICellRendererAngularComponent](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/) interface. There I can inject the ElementRef and on the lifecycle hook [AfterContentChecked](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentChecked) I check the parents' parent for the css-class 'ag-row-hover' and if it's there, I will show this additional button in the renderer component.

custom-cell.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-cell',
  template: `
      <ng-container *ngIf="hovered; else notHovered">{{form.value * form.value}}
        <button (click)="doStuff(form.value)">show root</button></ng-container>
      <ng-template #notHovered>{{form.value + form.value}}</ng-template>
  `,
})
export class CustomCellComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp, AfterContentChecked {
  form: FormControl;
  params: ICellRendererParams;
  hovered = false;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  doStuff(val) {
    alert(val);
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.hovered = (this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement)
      .parentElement
      .parentElement
      .classList.contains('ag-row-hover');
  }
}
```

The source code for this is on [github](https://github.com/phhbr/row-hover)

What do I want to improve?
I want to improve the performance and not having explicit checks for this behaviour. I'd rather have a directive with the css-selector '.ag-row', which I can inject to the ICellRendererAngularComponent and then check for the css class '.ag-row-hover' on every check. Or have a directive with the css-selector '.ag-row-hover' which is there, or is not. Anyone has any ideas how to improve my existing solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually achieve the desired behavior with CSS only, no need to inject ElementRef or do anything via Angular Lifecycle Callbacks.

That being said, your custom renderer could look something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-custom-cell",
  template: `
    <span style="color: red;">
      <div class="visible-on-hover">
        {{ form.value * form.value }}
        <button (click)="doStuff(form.value)">show root</button>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-on-hover">{{ form.value + form.value }}</div>
    </span>
  `
})
export class CustomCellComponent
  implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  form: FormControl;
  params: ICellRendererParams;

  constructor() {}

  doStuff(val) {
    alert(val);
  }

//... other stuff 

}
```

In your styles.scss (or somewhere it fits better, just [make sure the styles apply](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope)), just add these rules:

```
div.visible-on-hover {
  display: none;
}

.ag-row-hover {
  div.visible-on-hover {
    display: block;
  }

  div.hidden-on-hover {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Conceptually, the browser rendering engine then does what you did in ngAfterContentChecked().

Comment: Thanks for this clue. It solves the issue about using the lifecycle hooks of angular and may be a way better solution - performance wise.